# Why does OBJECT require an explicit end tag?

Tags: html

In the following example, the word "Goodbye" doesn't render (in Chrome 14, anyway):

```
<html>
<body>

<p>Hello</p>

<object width="400" height="400" data="helloworld.swf"/>

<p>Goodbye</p>

</body>
</html>
```

However, it does render when I add an explicit end tag to object:

```
<html>
<body>

<p>Hello</p>

<object width="400" height="400" data="helloworld.swf"></object>

<p>Goodbye</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Since I'm not supplying any parameters to my object and I don't want anything to show up if the object fails to load, it seems like the first syntax should be allowed.  Is anyone aware of a specific reason why this is disallowed?

Comment: Other than "the spec defines which tags can be self-closed and which can't", what more do you want?

Comment: Strange enough, either code works in Firefox 6. I'd expect the behavior as mentioned by robertc.

Comment: @g.d.d.c I was interested in the rationalization behind it, if any.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because `object` should contain fallback content in case the browser doesn't support, or doesn't have access to a plugin which supports, the content the `object` element references.

Comment: Thank you.  It's what I suspected, but I wasn't sure if I was missing some deeper reason.

Answer (score -1):

Because it is specified to be that way.